# SyntaxError while restoring MongoDB dump

Tags: mongodb

I am facing this error `SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):0`. I am using ubuntu. I have tried like this. First open the terminal and type mongo

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
>
```

after that I have switched to the database I want to create `test1` then used the folowing command

```
./mongorestore -h localhost:27017 -d test1 /home/ratheesh/testdev
```

I got this error

```
Wed May 16 12:33:03 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):0
>
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

`mongodump`, `mongorestore` etc. are executable programs and are not supposed to be run from mongo shell. Run the restore command from the command line and after running it start mongo and verify that the data appeared in database.